# mysql timeout in wordpress due to wp_options table exceeding 10gb

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm getting this proxy error

```
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.

The proxy server could not handle the request GET/@@@@@@.net/

Reason: Error reading from remote server;
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at hostgator.com Port 443
```

Response from Hostgator:

> The site is currently expericing MySQL timeout due to the queries that
>   the site is processing is exceeding the maxium time allowed. The query
>   which is getting killed by the server is attempting to exicute "SELECT
>   option_name, option_value FROM wp_options WHERE autoload = 'yes' " and
>   this is most likely occurring due to the wp_options database table
>   being in excess of 10GB.

How to change MySQL timeout / maximum time allowed? Where can change and where can i find these settings?

Comment: If you're using shared hosting, you can't, and you wouldn't want to. You should try optimizing your database and queries. Try adding an index to the autoload column.

Comment: Also, why is your `wp_options` table so huge?

Comment: You probably have a plugin creating a large number of transients in that table. You will need to focus your efforts on taming that plugin.

Comment: Will it resolve if I upgrade to Reseller to Dedicated??? Hostgator is not allowing to change execution time in php.in @ Reseller but I can in dedicated... do you feel this will resolve our problem???